# Evaluation of composition of mathematical functions

Tags: c#, math, optimization

I am evaluating the following function :

```
// evaluates exp(-z * (-log(x))^y )
// 0 < x < 1, y > 0, z > 0 
public static double f(double x, double y, double z)
{
    return Math.Exp(-z * Math.Pow(-Math.Log(x), y));
}
```

As this is something based on rather common functions, I was wondering : Are there some libraries (or better native C# ways) that could do it faster ?

Comment: If your program is running at 32 bits, you could try running it at 64 bits (`Environment.Is64BitProcess`). At 64 bits the .NET should use SSE2 instructions that are a little faster than x87 instructions...

Comment: It is running at 64bits already...

Comment: Faster?  You mean to run?  Develop?  Execute in what problem?  A faster algorithm?  Another equivalent function?

Comment: Faster to run, ideally. This specific function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Big Picture: No.

You might be able to find an implementation which compromises accuracy in favor of performance though (maybe using estimation and lookups).